# python 2.7, creating dictionary by zip from 2 lists, repeated key disappeared from the dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, zip

I am new to programming (1st month learning python and this is my first language.) 
 
While I play around with the dictionary methods I realized that the dictionary I created with the built-in zip function seems to randomly pick a repeated key to be shown in the dictionary as the keys. 
**Which results the other repeated key being skipped.** 
Can anyone explain to me in plain terms on why is this happening?
Thank you for your input.
(I roughly browsed some articles but because of my lack of knowledge.  I failed to find any answer to my question from the archive.)

```
x = "kekelala"
y = range(8)
d = dict(zip(x,y)) 
print "this is d", d.items()
```

The following are the key/value pairs of the dictionary d
 [('a', 7), ('k', 2), ('e', 3), ('l', 6)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each key in the dictionary must be unique (in your case, the letters stored in the variable `x`).

For example, if your dictionary had `{'k':0}`, and then you inserted `('k',2)`, the value with key `k` (i.e. the entry `('k',0)`) is overwritten.